# vaadin manage jpacontainer-addon with ivy

Tags: java, ivy, vaadin7

I woult create a vaadin project in Eclipse, with vaadin plugin, that use eclipselink to persist data. This is first time I use it and I can't configure ivy to download automatically jpacontainer-addon. I looked for the proper configuration entry in http://mvnrepository.com, but I was able to find only the configuration for version 1.x while current is 3.1.1. Is there a way to manage jpacontainer dependency with ivy or must I do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found by myself looking at the maven conf file of the addressbook-demo. The dependency name is not jpacontainer-addon anymore but jpacontainer only.

```
<dependency org="com.vaadin.addon" name="jpacontainer" rev="3.1.1"/>
```